# Simple Notifier in c#?

Tags: c#

I am making a simple notifier in c# on timer control 1 i have put interval of 10s to show an animated gif.The image shows after 10s when the program runs.But i want to show that picture for 10s and then hide again for 10s and then show again after 10s.Following is my code

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notifier.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\bounce.gif");
    }
```

Comment: what's the type of your notifier object?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, initially how did you hide the image?

Comment: @MatthiasKoch its a picturebox control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the image location once (I.e not in the tick event handler). And then on every interval just set the Visible property equal to the value of the Visible property `NOT`. That will switch visibility every interval. True for ten seconds, false for ten seconds, true for ten seconds...so on and so forth.

`yourImage.Visible = !yourImage.Visible;`

Answer (score 0):

Try it in timer code and put timer value to 10s

```
int vis=0;
if(vis==0)
{
   notifier.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\bounce.gif");
}
if(vis%2==0)
{
  notifier.visible=true;
}
else
{
 notifier.visible=false;
}
vis++;
```

or

```
bool vis=0;
if(vis==0)
{
   notifier.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\bounce.gif");
   vis++;
}
notifier.visible = !notifier.visible;
```

Comment: Or, more concisely notifier.visible = !notifier.visible